# Regex: Line does NOT contain a number

Tags: regex

I've been racking my brain for hours on this and I'm at my wit's end. I'm beginning to think that this isn't possible for a regular expression.

The closest thing I've seen is this post: [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word), but the solution doesn't work when I replace "hede" with the number.

I want to select EACH *line* that DOES NOT contain: **377681** so that I can delete it.

```
^((?!377681).)*$
```

...doesn't work, along with thousands of other examples/tweaks that I've found or done.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can't match what you don't want to match.

Comment: @webarto: Actually, there is an algorithm which takes an FA recognizing a language L over alphabet E and produces an FA recognizing L^C, the complement of L on E... so you are provably incorrect.

Comment: @Patrick87, I'm sure there is, but negating the match would solve him his many hour brain wracking :)

Comment: Why don't you just invert the predicate?  If you're using `grep`, use the `-v` command line option.  If you're using a regex library in some programming language, change `if (matches)` to `if (!matches)`.

Comment: OP here. I might be able to help you help me. In EACH line is the string "Account:" (without quotes). Is there a way to select a line with "Account: XXX" within it, as long as it does NOT contain the number "377681"?

Comment: wrack (v) to destroy; rack (v) to torture

Answer (score 2):

Would `grep -v 377681 input_file` solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
^(?!.*377681).+$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ubi5)

Important here is to use the `m` (multiline) modifier, so that `^` match the start of the line and `$` the end of the row, other wise it will not work.

(Note: I recognized that my regex has the same meaning than yours.)

Comment: If `^((?!377681).)*$`  does not work in the OP's case, then `^(?!.*377681).+$` won't either, AFAIK. The problem lies in the fact that `^` and `$` do no match line-starts and endings. I.e., the `m` flag needs to be enabled.

Comment: @Bart, yep you are right (+1) (its a bit late, I needed some time to understand that `^((?!377681).)*$` is quite the same than my solution)

Comment: Yeah, they do pretty much the same thing. A bit odd that you received a down-vote for an answer (your link does use the `m` flag!) that does work. I expect out math genius, Patrick87, to be a vindictive down-voter (my answer got down-voted as well) :)

Comment: @Bart I am already wondering why nearly every answer here is downvoted, since we know nothing about the context or the language and most of the answers are not bad/wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way of doing this, like for example iterating each line and asking for a built `String` method, like `indexOf` or `contains` depending on the language you're using.

Could you give us the full example?

Comment: Probably our math genius who is vindictively down-voting answers because he doesn't like the comment to his own silly answer. +1 to counter it.

Comment: @Bart I don't think so, he didn't seem like a "revenge" kind of guy, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to enable the `m` (multi-line) flag for the `^` and `$` to match the start- and end-of-lines respectively. If you don't, `^` will match the start-of-input and `$` will only match the end-of-input.

The following demo:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$text = 'foo 377681 bar
this can be 3768 removed
377681 more text
remove me';

echo preg_replace('/^((?!377681).)*$/m', '---------', $text);
?>
```

will print:

```
foo 377681 bar
---------
377681 more text
---------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$lines = array(
'434343343776815456565464',
'434343343774815456565464',
'434343343776815456565464'
);

foreach($lines as $key => $value){
    if(!preg_match('#(377681)#is', $value)){
        unset($lines[$key]);
    }   
}

print_r($lines);

?>
```